# TensorFlow `train.batch` skip 3 examples

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, queue

I have a model that utilizes TensorFlow's train.batch. The queue is constructed using an ordered set of strings corresponding to saved images. Items are dequeued to run inference during training. While the order is maintained there is a consistent skip of 3 in the queue.

The images in a single batch are continuous but regardless of how many images I draw from the queue, how often I draw from the queue, and the number of threads I use for the queue and whether I summarize, there is a skip of 3 across batches.

I have checked that the inference step is only called once and no other ops call the queue. Any insight would be appreciated Thanks!

Queue

```
with tf.name_scope('gather_data'):
    image_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(self.filenames,num_epochs=epochs, seed=seed, shuffle=shuffle)
    decoded_images = [self.vanilla_decode(image_queue)]
    if self.lag_steps > 0:
        lag_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(self.lag_filenames, num_epochs=epochs, seed=seed, shuffle=shuffle)
            decoded_lags = [self.vanilla_decode(lag_queue)]
            decoded_images += decoded_lags
    data = tf.train.batch(decoded_images,
                              num_threads=threads,
                              batch_size=self.batch_size,
                              capacity=capacity,
                              enqueue_many=True)
```

The only call to `video_G`, which is the sole user of the queue aside from the summary

```
if step % self.sum_freq == 0:
    frames, summ = self.sess.run([self.video_G, self.video_summ])
    self.sv.summary_computed(self.sess, summ, step)
else:
    frames = self.sess.run(self.video_G)
```

Comment: Could you try setting `allow_smaller_final_batch` to `True` in `tf.train.batch`? I wonder if it could be just that you miss the elements of the final batch.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue because it happens right away